# Redirecting another page when the page loading in Seam Framework

Tags: security, jsf, seam, seam2

I am developing Seam application. There is a special scenario for newly created users. When the user account is created by admin, he should change password in first login so I should force the user to change his password. In every page I have to control whether his first login or not, If it is first login I should redirect him to change password page.

I could not be success implementing this issue in Seam Framework.

Have you any ideas about this?

Answer (score 4):

I have two suggestions. First one,

Create a method in a bean which returns if a user logged in first time. Then in your pages.xml,

```
    <page view-id="*">
.
.

        <navigation from-action="#{identityBean.isFirstLogin()}">
            <rule if-outcome="true">
                <redirect view-id="/changePasswordPage.xhtml"/>
            </rule>
        </navigation>
   </page>
```

Second one is to use 'org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful' event.

```
@Observer("org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful")
public void redirectUserToChangePassword() {

     if ( isFirstLogin() ) {

            Redirect redirect = Redirect.instance();
            redirect.setViewId("/changePassword.xhtml");
            redirect.execute();

     }
}
```

But you can use this method if you are using seam security.

Comment: First one looks good but it runs in every request, that's right?

Comment: Observer approach is not secure, user can change URL and go in site without changing password. I do not want to let him go in without changing password.

Comment: Firstthumb, do you consider using activation links instead of your scenario? You send an activation link to user and disable LOGIN until user gets a password. So nobody can go nowhere. But this time you have to check if user logged in or not. On the other hand, i don't see a difference between checking if a user logged in or logging in for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a filter & can check there for newly created users & then can redirect them appropriately. Provide custom url-pattern to filter requests accordingly.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This isn't really a good approach. This filter will get applied on all request for all users all the time.